# JQuery-ui 1.8.2 draggable malfunctioning in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm maintaining a jquery/php filearchive for the company I work at.

One of the features is the ability to drag files into folders. This functionality works wonders in both Chrome and FireFox but exhibits peculiar behaviour in Internet Explorer.

What happens is that when a drag is initiated on an item a selection rectangle is created. The intended item is dragged along, and removed from its initial position, so in that regard the plugin is working. The problem is that all the other files receive select events when the selection box passes over them, not only is this not intended, it is also ugly.
I have tried to include all the relevant code here:
*Edit: I tried also including the css as a pastebin, but as the noob I am in here, I was only allowed to make one link*

[js](http://pastebin.com/wp17LUTe)

The versions used of jquery and jquery-ui is 1.4.4 and 1.8.2 respectively

The file divs are made draggable at line 919 in the js file.
I have googled quite a bit and also looked at the jquery demo pages, where the draggable interface works as intended, also in Internet Explorer.

I hope someone will be able to help me escape from this frustrating pit of cross-browser compatibility hell by means of showing me the way of my mistakes.

Request more information as needed, I will try to provide it in a timely manner.

Best regards,
Johan Abildskov

Comment: IE is broken...what else is new? :)

Comment: While I do apreciate your wit, and quite agree with the statement, I was hoping for something a bit more hands-on to help me with my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was actually resolved when I removed draggable from some of the items also being draggable.
Seems draggable and droppable actually conflicted abit in the way we used it.